# Hebrew Passwords on WinXP

Tags: localization, passwords, windows-xp, right-to-left

What is the accepted way for entering passwords in Hebrew / Hebrew localised installations? Should the password entry dialog be right aligned with new characters appending on the left? like this:

```
|----------------------|
|              |*******|
|----------------------|
```

Or do they generally left align with new characters inserted to the left? like this:

```
|----------------------|
||*******              |
|----------------------|
```

Or is it some other layout?

I'm doing some mock-ups of a Hebrew version of the software I'm working on and want to know what the normal way to do this is so the mock-up is correct.

Comment: Or any other RTL language for that matter...

Answer (score 2):

Taking a quick look around, it looks like a lot of applications translated to/written for Hebrew are RTL:

[image: facebook]
<sub>(source: [allfacebook.com](http://www.allfacebook.com/images/fb-hebrew.gif))</sub>

[image: domino.doc]

Can you ask whoever tasked you to create these mock-ups what they would prefer? Or make one of each and see which one looks/works better.

.02

Comment: Unfortunately, the people requesting the change are American and they're trying to sell the product to companies in Israel. So, no one knows what a typical Israelli user expects with a password entry field. I don't think that asking the people you're selling to how to make the product would look that good.

Comment: I would be flattered if a company cared enough to ask how I want their software to look. Also, if you're trying to sell your product in the Israeli market without even some basic knowledge about their culture and preferences, your product is going to fail. Just saying...

Answer (score 2):

In gnome, the alignment of the password textbox automatically changes when the user switches the keyboard between Hebrew and English modes. This serves as another hint to whether the password being typed is in the right keyboard layout.

Comment: So, that's the upper ascii art layout then. It is the way I would expect, but the project manager thought otherwise. The input method hint (i.e. which side the cursor is on) is useful.